# Toast does not work in webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Here is my code, this is literally step by step from developer.android.com

and it just doesn't work, no matter how many times I run it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);


        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /** Show a toast from the web page */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

When I run my app, the webpage will load, toast never shows.

I just can't seem to find the problem. Can someone tell me if this works for them?

EDIT: Here is some more that I'm confused about. Right after this, the instructions are

> This creates an interface called Android for JavaScript running in the
>   WebView. At this point, your web application has access to the
>   WebAppInterface class. For example, here's some HTML and JavaScript
>   that creates a toast message using the new interface when the user
>   clicks a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

I have no idea where that part of js code goes either..

Comment: Where's the code that actually calls `showToast()`?

Comment: I think you misread the tutorial. It says : _"In this example, the WebAppInterface class allows the web page to create a Toast message, using the showToast() method."_ Try to create an html page, and load it in your webview, like it's done in the tutorial.

Comment: Is it a code in the google website?

Comment: I edited my post for more clarification.

Comment: Also, lallto, to address your question.. 

isn't this created in `onCreate();` I assume it would happen automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have no idea where that part of js code goes either..

Create an html page in your assets folder, let's say named `myWonderfulWebPage.html`.

Copy the following HTML code to it :

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, when you'll click the button, the function `showAndroidToast` will be called and this function will call the one you defined in your Java code.

Now go back in your activity and load this page into your webview :

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myWonderfulWebPage.html");
```

Now you will see that it shows a blank page, with a button. Click it and it will show you the `Toast` on your webpage.

Comment: Thank you, that put a lot of things into perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you show is what is actually used then of course it will not work.

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

**Google.com does not invoke the JS function** you have added a bridge to. You need to use **your own webpage** that does indeed invoke the function, either local or on the web.-.-

Comment: Thank's, I'm new to this, excuse my idiocy.