# android Cannot run Java function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, android

In my project I have a `WebView` which loads a page (HTML). 
I want to change all images and show a toast when a user clicks on any image.

So I'm adding javascript code which calls Java function:

```js
// code is inside onPageFinished(..) function
JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(activity);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");

webView.evaluateJavascript(
  "var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');" +
  "for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {" +
  "imgs[i].src = 'file:///android_asset/rules_images_placeholder.png';" +
  "imgs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {" +
  "window.JSInterface.showToast(); " + // <-- isn't called: see logs
  "});" +
  "} " +
  "window.JSInterface.showToast();" // <-- is called
  , null);
```

> JavaScriptInterface class:

```js
public class JavaScriptInterface {
  private Activity activity;
  public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
  }
  @JavascriptInterface
  public void showToast() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

---

`showToast()` should be called when

1. page has finished loading
2. user has clicked on image

Problem: `showToast()` is called only once - when page has finished loading.
When the user clicks on image, `showToast()` isn't called, instead the following log appears:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showToast' of undefined",
>   source:

**Question**

How to call `showToast()` on image click?

Comment: This is definitely how you would do it (provided the first call works, as you say). Have you simplified the example too much, perhaps, compared to your real code (if this isn't your real code)? Specifically, in your real code, are you using `i` from within the event handler? Because that would be [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: T.J. Crowder: Actually I haven't simplified the code - I have cut and pasted it.

Comment: In that case, you need to look at what's changed since page load and the click. The error message is telling you that `window.JSInterface` is (now) `undefined`, whereas it had a different value (a reference to your object) earlier. For some reason that changed. I don't think we can tell from what's in the question above *what* changed, but that's what you want to look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why, but you can fix this problem by adding a JavaScript interface prior to loading your HTML content.

```
jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(activity);
fragmentWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
fragmentWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
fragmentWebView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");

fragmentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", fullHtml, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
fragmentWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        view.loadUrl(
            "javascript:var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');" +
            "for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {" +
            "imgs[i].src = 'file:///android_asset/rules_images_placeholder.png';" +
            "imgs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {" +
            "window.JSInterface.showToast(); " +
            "});" +
            "}" +
            "console.log(window.JSInterface);" +
            "window.JSInterface.showToast(); ");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the evaluateJavascript methoad and use loadUrl. Try the below code its working for me:-

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {


        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("checking", "MYmsg");

            webView.loadUrl("javascript: var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');" +
                    "for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {" +

                    "imgs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {" +
                    "window.CallToAnAndroidFunction.showToast(); " +    
                    "});" +
                    "} " );


        }
    });
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(Main2Activity.this),
            "CallToAnAndroidFunction");
```

Interface:-

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have `<img>` tags
try adding them first and check

Android function

```
WebView webView= findViewById(R.id.webview);
    JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");

    webView.evaluateJavascript(

            "document.write('<img>');" +
                    "document.write('<img>');\n"+
                    "var x = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');" +
                    "console.log(x.length);"+
                    "for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {" +
                    "x[i].src = 'https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/images/badge_overlay.png';" +
                    "x[i].addEventListener('click', function() {" +
                    "window.JSInterface.showToast(); " +    // <-- now calling :)
                    "});" +
                    "} " +
                    "window.JSInterface.showToast();"   // <-- is called
            , null);
```

or you can load html content from assets first. with `webView.loadUrl();`

Answer (score 0):

You no need to wait for image appearance at dom level.

```
 string code = `
     document.addEventListener("click",(e)=> {
        if(e.target instanceof Image){
            window.JSInterface.showToast();
        }
     });`
 webView.evaluateJavascript(code, null);
```

At this example I used string literals => https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155171/5138198

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking the Javascript function where you actually call Java and place it inside the html page related to the webview. Place it at headers, so it will definitively be present when click event later takes place, and won't disappear after any evaluation of function, like it probably does now in your case.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        JSInterface.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

**Sources I found of similar cases refer always to separate html:**

[1] [Toast does not work in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215194/toast-does-not-work-in-webview)

[2] [Android WebView showToast onButtonClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779954/android-webview-showtoast-onbuttonclick)